# create dictionary for key: value from two dimension list

Tags: python, python-3.x

is there any other way to parse multiple dimensional list into set in python? the other way, I can think of is create a dictionary and then put element into set one by one. any other more efficient way to do it??

```
graph = {i: set() for l in triplets for i in l}
{graph[c[i]].add(c[i - 1]) for c in triplets for i in range(2, 0, -1)}
#input
tri = [    
  ['t','u','p'],
  ['w','h','i'],
  ['t','s','u'],
  ['a','t','s'],
  ['h','a','p'],
  ['t','i','s'],
  ['w','h','s'] 
]
#i want the output
key is chat of each element from tri, value is the all chat in front of key in each element from tri
like u:{t}, ....
{
    u:{'t', 's'}
    p:{'u', 'a'}
    h:{'w'}
    i:{'h', 't'}
    s:{'t', 'i', 'h'}
    t:{'a'}
    a:{'h'}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through each sublist in the list and create output dictionary with key as element and values as a set of previous elements of that element in all sublists.

```
tri = [    
  ['t','u','p'],
  ['w','h','i'],
  ['t','s','u'],
  ['a','t','s'],
  ['h','a','p'],
  ['t','i','s'],
  ['w','h','s'] 
]

d = {}
for x in tri:
    for y in x[1:]:
        d.setdefault(y, set()).update(x[x.index(y) - 1])

print(d)

# {'u': {'s', 't'}, 
#  'p': {'a', 'u'},
#  'h': {'w'}, 
#  'i': {'h', 't'},
#  's': {'h', 'i', 't'},
#  't': {'a'},
#  'a': {'h'}}
```

*Note* that order of values for keys might change because we are using a `set` which is an unordered collection.

Comment: nice, thank you. so i guess i can build dict comprehension in one line

Comment: Yes, [`setdefault`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_setdefault.htm) is a great function to use when you aren't sure whether or not a key is in a dictionary.